# worksheet problem...Prove the set of all subsets of N is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countably infinite. 
I understand what countably infinite means but I don't know how to arrange the subsets according to their sum and I can't figure out how to form the proof
Please help 
thanks

Comment: All subsets (as in the header) or all finite subsets (as in the body)? It might make a difference.

Comment: Each real number between $0$ and $1$ gives rise to a subset of $\mathbb N$ by truncating the decimal.  For example, $\pi-3=.141592653\dots $ gives the subset $\{1,14,141,1415,14159,141592,\cdots\}$.  Hence if you don't require finite the assertion is false.

Comment: Map any finite sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ into $\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}$ where the $p_i$ are the primes.